# Arrow r error, out of memory: realloc of size failed

Tags: r, dplyr, apache-arrow

I am doing different data processing operations over a big dataset (approx 50M rows per 14 columns, some of them being strings of no more than 14 characters) using `arrow`. I have used `open_dataset` to manipulate the data using arrow. After doing several operations, I am able to call `compute` on a final dataset I use before some grouping and summarising operations within a for loop. Based on this dataset, the code is the following:

*Note: `summarise_numeric` is a custom function that summarises several variables*

```r
geo_groupings <- list(national = "", 
                      region = "region",
                      zip_code = "Zip Code")
var_groupings <- list(unsegmented = "",
                      no_gender = c("Age"),
                      no_age = c("Gender"),
                      all_variables = c("Gender", "Age"))

sales <- sales %>% compute()
# 3.2 Variables creation:
for (geo_group in names(geo_groupings)){
  for (var_group in names(var_groupings)){
    groups <- c("date", "customer")
    if (var_group != "unsegmented") groups <- c(groups, var_groupings[[var_group]])
    if (geo_group != "national") groups <- c(groups, geo_groupings[[geo_group]])
    groups <- rlang::syms(groups)
    
    stacked <- sales %>% 
      group_by(!!!groups[1:length(groups)]) %>% 
      summarise_numeric() %>% 
      mutate(Segment = tolower(paste(!!!groups[2:length(groups)], sep = "_"))) %>% 
      relocate(Segment, .after = "date") %>% 
      # We collect because there is not an implementation of tidyr::pivot_wider
      # for the arrow package yet
      collect()
```

Then I get the following error:

```r
#> Error in `compute.arrow_dplyr_query()`:
#> ! Out of memory: realloc of size 8589934656 failed
```

The code works perfectly, the only issue is memory reallocation. I need to call `collect` because then I need to apply `pivot_wider` to `stacked` and this is not implemented as of `arrow` 11.0.0.3.

An example of how I would approach this example with `arrow::map_batches` in order to circumvent memory issues is the following:

```r
map_batches(iris_dt, function(batch){
  batch %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum))  
}) %>% 
  collect()
```

For this particular example, it has the same result as

```r
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum)) %>% 
  collect()
```

However, when calling the same code in my big dataset

```r
 stacked <- arrow::map_batches(sales, function(batch){
   batch %>%
     group_by(!!!groups[1:length(groups)]) %>% 
     summarise_numeric() %>% 
     mutate(customer = tolower(paste(!!!groups[2:length(groups)], sep = "_"))) %>% 
     relocate(customer, .after = "date") 
 }) %>% 
  collect()
```

The result that I get is not perfectly aggregated as you would expect from a `group_by` and `summarise` operation. I am wondering whether using the `.lazy = FALSE` argument would solve this issue.

Comment: If you have a determinate set of columns to spread to, you can use `arrow::map_batches()` as an alternative to `collect()`, which can let you iterate over RecordBatches instead of collecting the full dataset at once.

Comment: @alistaire Could you please provide an example of how you would, for instance, create a batch for each relevant column in the data in my particular example?

Comment: RecordBatches are batches of records (rows) with all columns. In a lot of regards they behave like Arrow Tables/dataframes, though they're not, exactly—they're slightly lower-level. [Here are some docs.](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/RecordBatch.html) `map_batches()` iterates over the RecordBatch instances in your Dataset, so if you can transform each batch consistently to whatever you want, you can transform the whole dataset without collecting. For an answer, you'll need to create [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4497050) with sample data.

Comment: Thank you for the response @alistaire. I am sorry but the data that I'm processing here is a bit sensitive so I am not able to reproduce the exact example here. However, I will edit the question including an example with the `iris` dataset so that you can see what I have done and what my question is

Comment: @alistaire My main question is whether using `map_batches` allows me to process the whole dataset in chunks, since the results that I got with my big dataset unexpectedly still require further aggregation