# How to use the arrow map_batches function to process an arrow dataset in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, memory-management, apache-arrow

I am trying to process a dataset that is larger than what my RAM allows. To this end, I am using `arrow` to manipulate the dataset as outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75978694/arrow-r-error-out-of-memory-realloc-of-size-failed). However, when doing the final processing my R session is not able to handle all memory requirements and crashes.

To avoid this, another user suggested using the `arrow::map_batches` function to process the arrow dataset by batches. However, there are no examples in the [documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/map_batches.html), and those of other [vignettes](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/dataset.html#batch-processing-experimental) do not properly explain the functioning either.

My intention is to process the whole dataset, but allowing the session to process it by batches instead of all at once and prevent R from crashing. This is the code that I have used:

```r
# sales is an arrow Dataset
# groups is a set of variables I use for grouping
stacked <- arrow::map_batches(sales, function(batch){
  batch %>%
    group_by(!!!groups[1:length(groups)]) %>% 
    summarise_numeric() %>% 
    mutate(customer_type = tolower(paste(!!!groups[2:length(groups)], sep = "_"))) %>% 
    relocate(customer_type, .after = "date") 
    
}) %>%
  # We collect because there is not an implementation of tidyr::pivot_wider
  # for the arrow package yet 
  collect()
     
variables <- stacked %>% 
  select(c("date", "customer_type") | where(is.numeric)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "date", names_from = "customer_type", values_from = where(is.numeric)) %>% 
  rename_with(~paste0("kpi_", .), .cols = where(is.numeric))
```

Even though now the process up to `stacked` is able to finish, the table that is returned has more than one observation per group, it is as if the batches remain in the collected dataset; but I would like them to be completely grouped before creating the `variables` dataframe.

Any help on how to use the `arrow::map_batches` function is much appreciated.